Why the first FlyoutItem stop Working? navigation problem IOS
When I navigate to the Formaciones section, it works perfectly for me but when I try to go back to Home it doesn't come back, but if I have TabBar (I set it to True) it does work. This only happens to me on IOS, on Android it works for me. I'm in Maui 8.0.6
 <FlyoutItem Route="DashboardPage" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

     <ShellContent  Title="Home"   
     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dashboardPages:DashboardPage}"
    />

     <ShellContent  Title="Formaciones"    
     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate formacionPages:ActoView}"
    />

 </FlyoutItem>

 <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
     <StackLayout Padding="30">
         <Button WidthRequest="120" CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="DarkCyan" Text="Sing Out" Command="{Binding SignOutCommand}"/>
     </StackLayout>
 </Shell.FlyoutFooter>

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new AppShellViewModel();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DashboardPage), typeof(DashboardPage));
         Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ActoView), typeof(ActoView));
    }
}

In my MauiProgram.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DashboardPage>();

Because it works for me in andorid and not in IOS (I'm using an iPhone 14 IOS 16.4 emulator)
I want it to work for me through FlyoutMenu, not through TabBar
if I change and dashboard I put it down it stops working Formaciones that is above, It's like the first one won't let me tap

I have seen that it is a bug in the version of Maui 8.0.6 I leave here a link: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19071

I cannot reproduce your question based on the code. Does it navigate by clicking the flyout item?

@LiqunShen-MSFT the issue was fixed in 8.0.7
